# CompileError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

Tags: python, memory, pystan

Every time I run this loop, it only runs for 3-6 iterations before throwing me this error. I'm almost positive its due to a memory issue since hF.BHDMS_fit() is a really computationally expensive function. In order to restart the loop i have to clear my kernal in my jupyter notebook and run it again. I'm running this off a decently powerful server but I dont know how to get past this error, i even tried to use garbage collect. Any suggestions so i can run this loop without having to restart the kernal every 5 iterations?

Loop:

```
n = 100  # Number of neurons
start = 88 #Firing rate in Hz
finish = 95 #Firing rate in Hz
total_time = 1  # Total time in seconds
bin_size = 0.01  # Bin size in seconds
num_trials = 100  # Number of trials
 
stored_lambda = []

for r in range(start, finish):
    spike_counts_matrix = simulate_trials_poisson_neurons(n, r, total_time, bin_size, num_trials)
    possible_codewords = (hF.extract_unique_codewords(spike_counts_matrix, n_cores=4)).T
    sampled_cw = possible_codewords[np.random.choice(possible_codewords.shape[0], size=299, replace=False), :]
    dmat = hF.hamming_distance_matrix(sampled_cw)
    fit = hF.BHMDS_fit(sampled_cw, 2, 100, dmat)
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    stored_lambda.append(fit[1]['lambda'])
    
    #explicitly delete large objects
    del spike_counts_matrix, possible_codewords, sampled_cw, dmat, fit
    gc.collect()
```

error:

```
/tmp/ccl1ZBv9.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccl1ZBv9.s: Fatal error: can't close /tmp/pystan_10oiqnom/tmp/pystan_10oiqnom/stanfit4anon_model_83093fdb500d02ab161db95a3a9ac536_299748516262806981.o: No space left on device
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DistutilsExecError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py:185, in UnixCCompiler._compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    184 try:
--> 185     self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] + extra_postargs)
    186 except DistutilsExecError as msg:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py:1041, in CCompiler.spawn(self, cmd, **kwargs)
   1040 def spawn(self, cmd, **kwargs):
-> 1041     spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/spawn.py:70, in spawn(cmd, search_path, verbose, dry_run, env)
     69     cmd = cmd[0]
---> 70 raise DistutilsExecError(
     71     "command {!r} failed with exit code {}".format(cmd, exitcode)
     72 )

DistutilsExecError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 15
     13 sampled_cw = possible_codewords[np.random.choice(possible_codewords.shape[0], size=299, replace=False), :]
     14 dmat = hF.hamming_distance_matrix(sampled_cw)
---> 15 fit = hF.BHMDS_fit(sampled_cw, 2, 100, dmat)
     16 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
     17 stored_lambda.append(fit[1]['lambda'])

File /mnt/cube/jugorman/BHDMS/code/helperFxnzBHMDS_JCG.py:276, in BHMDS_fit(pts, dim, n_batch, dmat)
    273     dmat = 2.0 * dmat / np.max(dmat)
    275     # embed points in a given dimension 
--> 276     fit = HMDS.embed(dim, dmat)
    277     return dmat, fit
    278 else:

File /mnt/cube/jugorman/BHDMS/code/metric_HMDS.py:250, in embed(D, dij, initial_values, Niter)
    227 """
    228 Returns embedding of distance matrix and optimized parameter values
    229 Inputs:
   (...)
    246    'crs' - radial coordinates of points after CM translation
    247 """
    249 #compile model
--> 250 hmds_m = stan.StanModel(model_code=HMDS_code, verbose=False)
    252 N = len(dij)
    253 dat = {'N':N, 'D':D, 'deltaij':dij}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pystan-2.22.1.0.dev0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/pystan/model.py:396, in StanModel.__init__(self, file, charset, model_name, model_code, stanc_ret, include_paths, boost_lib, eigen_lib, verbose, obfuscate_model_name, extra_compile_args, allow_undefined, include_dirs, includes)
    393     orig_stderr = pystan.misc._redirect_stderr()
    395 try:
--> 396     build_extension.run()
    397 finally:
    398     if redirect_stderr:
    399         # restore stderr

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py:345, in build_ext.run(self)
    342     self.compiler.set_link_objects(self.link_objects)
    344 # Now actually compile and link everything.
--> 345 self.build_extensions()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py:467, in build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    465     self._build_extensions_parallel()
    466 else:
--> 467     self._build_extensions_serial()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py:493, in build_ext._build_extensions_serial(self)
    491 for ext in self.extensions:
    492     with self._filter_build_errors(ext):
--> 493         self.build_extension(ext)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py:548, in build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    545 for undef in ext.undef_macros:
    546     macros.append((undef,))
--> 548 objects = self.compiler.compile(
    549     sources,
    550     output_dir=self.build_temp,
    551     macros=macros,
    552     include_dirs=ext.include_dirs,
    553     debug=self.debug,
    554     extra_postargs=extra_args,
    555     depends=ext.depends,
    556 )
    558 # XXX outdated variable, kept here in case third-part code
    559 # needs it.
    560 self._built_objects = objects[:]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py:600, in CCompiler.compile(self, sources, output_dir, macros, include_dirs, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, depends)
    598     except KeyError:
    599         continue
--> 600     self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    602 # Return *all* object filenames, not just the ones we just built.
    603 return objects

File ~/anaconda3/envs/BHMDS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py:187, in UnixCCompiler._compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    185     self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] + extra_postargs)
    186 except DistutilsExecError as msg:
--> 187     raise CompileError(msg)

CompileError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please read and follow in the future [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular pay attention to the parts about writing a summary title about the **specific** problem. One way to think about it is to imagine you come upon the same **underlying** issue in the future and so you want to search the questions you asked in the past. In that case what title would jump out at you as being related? As to your problem, we cannot really get a sense of the scope and what you mean by 'a decently powerful server'.